# Receiving Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a BOOLEAN cell when exporting XML map

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I have a workbook with an XML mapping defined (I am using POI 4.1.2).

A mapped cell contains a formula which evaluates to boolean: `=AND(B70="";B71=""; B50="No")`

I try to export the XML mapping with the following code:

```
// First ensure that all formulas are evaluated
wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
// Export XML map
String file = "path/to/file.xml";
XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook) wb;
XSSFMap xssfMap = xssfWorkbook.getCustomXMLMappings().stream().findFirst().get();
XSSFExportToXml exporter = new XSSFExportToXml(xssfMap);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
exporter.exportToXML(out, false);
```

The last line results to the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a
> BOOLEAN cell  at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:1035)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(XSSFCell.java:319)
> at
> org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(DateUtil.java:765)
> at
> org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(DateUtil.java:744)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.extractor.XSSFExportToXml.mapCellOnNode(XSSFExportToXml.java:281)

When i look into `XSSFExportToXml.mapCellOnNode(XSSFCell, Node)` I see the following code:

```
private void mapCellOnNode(XSSFCell cell, Node node) {

    String value ="";
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {

    case STRING: value = cell.getStringCellValue(); break;
    case BOOLEAN: value += cell.getBooleanCellValue(); break;
    case ERROR: value = cell.getErrorCellString();  break;
    case FORMULA:
       if (cell.getCachedFormulaResultType() == CellType.STRING) { // cell.getCachedFormulaResultType() returns BOOLEAN
           value = cell.getStringCellValue();
       } else {
           if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) { // Results in Exception
              value = getFormattedDate(cell);
           } else {
              value += cell.getNumericCellValue();
           }
       }
       break;
    
    case NUMERIC: 
         if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
              value = getFormattedDate(cell);
          } else {
             value += cell.getRawValue();
          }
        break;

    default:

    }
    if (node instanceof Element) {
        Element currentElement = (Element) node;
        currentElement.setTextContent(value);
    } else {
        node.setNodeValue(value);
    }
}
```

From my understanding there is a bug in `mapCellOnNode`. Inside `case FORMULA` the expression `cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()` returns `BOOLEAN` but inside this block only `STRING` and `NUMERIC` are considered. This leads to executing `DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)` which results in an Exception.

**So my question is:** am I right? Is it a bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct, that code of `XSSFExportToXml.mapCellOnNode` is incomplete. A formula result type can not only be `CellType.STRING` or `CellType.NUMERIC`. It may be `CellType.BOOLEAN` and `CellType.ERROR` too. And that needs to be considered.

Comment: @AxelRichter Ok thanks. So how to proceed? Open a bug report on https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla?

Comment: I raised https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65492

Comment: @PJFanning You should answer the question now that you have fixed the bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have applied a fix to the POI code - see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65492 - this will be included in next POI release